# What do philosophers think about the beauty?

Tags: epistemology, metaphysics

When we see someone beautiful we understand what is beauty. The definition may not be absolute but it can be roughly defined. For example - symmetrical form may be considered beautiful. Fair color can be considered beautiful. Good nature can be considered beautiful.
Physicists are obsessed with symmetry as most of their cutting edge theories are [symmetrical](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_(physics)).

What do philosophers think about beauty ?
What would philosophers call beauty ? Is it absence of contradiction? Is it empirical evidence ? Or Is it logical deductibility ? Or there is no such concept of beauty in philosophy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ancient greeks like *Aristotle*, beauty was measurable with symmetry;other philosoper like *Freud* speculates also that the sense of beauty has its roots in sexual stimulation and principally in the libidinal excitation produced by looking at a sexual object (https://www.rep.routledge.com/)
Having different answers is dued to the fact that a philosopher more related to Freud thinks more in a neurological ways, instead of Descartes, Aristotle and so on that see it more in a mathematical and logical way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).